# How to read php array of string in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
var longitudeArray = new Array(<?php $result = count($longitudeArray);
                                    if ($result > 1){
                                    echo implode(',', $longitudeArray); 
                                    } else {
                                    echo $longitudeArray[0];
                                    }
                                    ?>);
```

`$longitudeArray` contain array of number like: `$longitudeArray = array(23.54545, 2323.32);`
Above script create following javascript array:

```
var longitudeArray = new Array(12.32444,21.34343,23.5454);
```

but if i passes string in `$longitudeArray` like:

```
$longitudeArray = array('one', 'two');
```

instead of integer value in `$longitudeArray` then my javascript array is not creating properly or its not working.

Comment: And how would you like it solved, should it fail with a descriptive error or should it convert one to 1 and two to 2 or what?

Comment: it is not showing any result and if if i read longitudeArray[0] then its not showing value at position 0

Comment: Are you seriously saying your code is *spelling* the numbers out?  Or do you mean they're just being interpreted by JavaScript as Strings, even though they're still numeric, e.g. ("12.32444", "21.34343", "23.5454")?!?!

Comment: ...and *how* is it not being created properly?  Because JavaScript is pretty good at understanding Strings containing a number, the confusion usually starts when addition results in concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an array of strings to your code, you will end up without quotes around them in your generated javascript code. You need to add some quotes somehow, something like:

```
var longitudeArray = new Array("<?php echo implode('","', $longitudeArray);?>");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
var longitudeArray=<?=json_encode($longitudeArray)?>;
```

Comment: JSON=JavaScript Object Notation~ it takes a PHP array and converts it to native JavaScript code~

Answer (score 0):

@Shad, very useful and efficient approach.  In the same manner, if one is trying to convert a PHP array to pass back to a JavaScript function (EG: an AJAX callback), that would be accomplished as such:

```
$some_php_array = array( 'indexA' => 'nice', 'indexB' => 'move' );
json_encode($some_php_array);
```

Where the PHP data would look as follows in JavaScript:

```
{"indexA":"nice","indexB":"move"}
```